# Which is the best way to setup Multiple devise sign_in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I think I am going at this the wrong way.
I am using Devise 3.5.3 and Rails 4.2.5
I have 3 different kinds of users: regular users, sellers and redeemers.
Each kind should have their own sign_in page, since Regular users login via Facebook only and sellers and redeemers sign in via email. 
So far I have set up my routes like this:

```
devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }

as :user do
  get 'seller', :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get 'redeemer', :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

I have a single new session view and I am showing sign_in options based on request URL as recommended in another StackOverflow answer

```
<% if request.fullpath.include?('sign_in') %>
  show Facebook Login
<% else %>
  show regular devise form
<% end %>
```

This works, after a fashion. My problem is that when invalid credentials are entered, devise will redirect to /users/sign_in page instead of /sellers or /redeemers URLs.

I could follow these instructions

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

to setup a custom redirect but I feel I am going at it the wrong way. The whole setup looks hackish.

I would appreciate any recommendations about the best practices for my use case.

Comment: I think you need only one devise form and one `omniauth facebook` button. You can differentiate that on the basis of url called. This link may help you http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

Comment: Really good reference `@PardeepDhingra`, thank you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will implement a single sign in screen as recommended and show different options based on url called. Will report back when done.

Answer (score 0):

> about the best practices

One of the primary adherents of good software development is [`Single Source of Truth`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) (although not applicable to your issue directly, highlights a major aspect of the answer) - keeping functionality as simple as possible. Rails touches on this with the [`DRY` convention](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/getting_started.html#drying-up-the-code).

In short, only have 1 set of functionality, reuse it infinitely.

--

I would say that **you need *one* sign-in route**. Your users don't care if they're `sellers`, `redeemers` or `standard users` -> they want to log into your app and get the functionality they need:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }
```

> since Regular users login via Facebook only and sellers and redeemers sign in via email

Why do you have multiple methods for different parties?

I think you're getting confused between authentication and authorization:

- Authentication = user logged in?
- Authorization  = user has permission?

In short, `authentication` / `Devise` should handle whether a user is logged in or not. This has nothing to do with login methodology; whether they use `facebook` or `email` should be irrelevant.

I would personally allow all users to login with whichever service they want, and then manage their access with an authorization implementation ([`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) etc).

--

Quite a broad answer, I'll delete it if irrelevant.

Comment: thanks for the broad answer. My web app relies heavily on Facebook for its value. Therefore regular users NEED to register / log in via Facebook. Other users like sellers and redeemers log in for administrative tasks. And we send them out the credentials once they signup for our service. In this case these NEED to be email logins, not Facebook. I do use cancan to limit what sellers / redeemers can do once logged in.